# Laravel Blade - Header & Footer in a Loop

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have data like this sorted by Category:

```
Category 1, Product 1, Amount
Category 1, Product 2, Amount
Category 2, Product 3, Amount
```

I like to print it using blade as

```
Category 1

Product 1    Amount
Product 2    Amount 
....
Total Amount of Category 1 : xxxxx


Category 2

Product 3    Amount 
....
Total Amount of Category 2 : xxxxx
```

Comment: I used

[@]foreach ($data as $row)

[@]endforeach 

I know how to display name of new category and amount total, the main problem is, I can not check which row is last of any particular category.

Comment: Why some one gave this question -1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that $categories is the sorted multidimensional array with indexes category,product and amount.

```
   @for ($i = 0; $i < count($categories) ; $i++)
         <?php $category_product_toatl=0; ?>
         {{ $categories[$i]['category'] }}
         {{ $categories[$i]['product'] }}     {{ $categories[$i]['amount']}}
         <?php 
              $category_product_total= $category_product_total+ $categories[$i]['amount'];
         ?>
         @for ($j = $i+1; $j < count($categories) ; $j++)
              @if($categories[$i]['category']== $categories[$j]['category'])
                     {{ $categories[$j]['product'] }}     {{ $categories[$j]['amount']}}
                     <?php 
                          $category_product_total= $category_product_total+ $categories[$j]['amount']; 
                     ?>
               @else
                     break;
               @endif

        @endfor
   Total Amount of {{ $category[$i] }} : {{ $category_product_total }}
@endfor
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. 

Is there a way to find which row is last for any category?

Comment: Yes where you write "break;" statement in the @else part that is the last row for any category.